# How to aggregate non-primary reputation in active record reputation system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

**Edit Note:** This is a question regarding the [activerecord-reputation-system gem](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system) covered in [Railscast#364](http://railscasts.com/episodes/364-active-record-reputation-system)

I have an application in which users of the `Vip` and `Peon` classes can vote for their favorite `Idea` object. I am able to successfully gather `vip_votes` and `peon_votes`. How can I aggregate the two vote types into `total_votes`? I have the code below, but the total_votes do not accumulate as expected.

**idea.rb**

```
has_reputation :vip_votes, 
               :source => :vip,
               :aggregated_by => :sum 

has_reputation :peon_votes, 
               :source => :peon,
               :aggregated_by => :sum 

has_reputation :total_votes, 
               :source => [{ :reputation => :vip_votes },
                           { :reputation => :peon_votes, :weight => 0.8 }],
               :aggregated_by => :sum
```

**ideas_controller.rb**

```
def vip_vote
  @design = Design.find(params[:id])
  @design.add_evaluation(:vip_votes, 1, current_vip)
end

def peon_vote
  @design = Design.find(params[:id])
  @design.add_evaluation(:peon_votes, 1, current_peon)
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :ideas do
  member { post :vip_vote }
  member { post :peon_vote }
end
```

Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared the library you're using for reputation which I presume provides the `has_reputation` class method and `add_evaluation` instance method

Comment: Hi @rossta. Good point. I have added the link to the ActiveRecord Reputation System gem to the top of the post.

Comment: And what is the typical result you see from `total_votes` compared to what you expect?

Comment: I don't see anything. I can add a vip_vote via the ideas#vip_vote, and the same for peon_vote. However, these votes do not get included in total_votes. I've tried adding a definition for total_votes, but that didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unable to resolve the issue, I resorted to physically adding the two composing vote types into an instance variable in the controller.

I use total_votes in my Idea#Show view file, so I added the following.

**ideas_controller.rb**

```
def show
@total_votes = @idea.reputation_value_for(:vip_votes).to_i + @idea.reputation_value_for(:peon_votes) * 0.8
end
```

Still, would appreciate it if anyone knows of a better way to do this.

Comment: I have a similar issue that I can't seem to get around.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246904/twitter-activerecord-reputation-counting-primary-reputations-as-non-primary-rep

Answer (score 0):

It may be too late for you this will hopefully help others.  I think the code you're after is found in the [Quick Start](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system#quick-start) for the activerecord-reputation-system gem:

Transposing what is done there to your problem reaps:

```
has_reputation :total_votes, 
               :source => [{ :reputation => :vip_votes },
                           { :reputation => :peon_votes, :weight => 0.8 }] # no comma here
               # this line seems to be assumed: :aggregated_by => :sum
```

Haven't tested it but hopefully helps...

Answer (score 0):

If Peon.rb has 'peons' table with reputation defined like this

```
has_reputation :votes, source: :user, aggregated_by: :sum
```

Then you should do this in Idea.rb for peon_votes.

```
 has_reputation :peon_votes,
    :source => {reputation: :votes, of: :peons}
```

The same thing applies with Vip.rb

Then to calculate the total votes in Idea.rb, you do this

```
has_reputation :total_votes, 
               :source => [{ :reputation => :vip_votes },
                           { :reputation => :peon_votes, :weight => 0.8 }],
               :aggregated_by => :sum
```