# Twitter ActiveRecord Reputation: Counting primary reputations as non-primary reputations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models: Voters and Polls.

A Voter can vote on a Poll in two ways: 1) up/down vote 2) power vote

I have up/down voting working, but I want to be able to know how many power votes a user has accumulated in aggregate as they can only have a certain amount.

**poll.rb**

```
class Poll < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :voter

  has_reputation :votes,
                 source: :voter

  has_reputation :powervotes,
                 source: :voter,
                 source_of: [{reputation: :voter_powervotes, of: :voter}]

  has_reputation :score,
                 source: [
                   { reputation: :votes },
                   { reputation: :powervotes, weight: 2 }]

  def upvote(voter)
    self.add_or_update_evaluation(:votes, 1, voter)
  end

  def downvote(voter)
    self.add_or_update_evaluation(:votes, -1, voter)
  end

  def powervote(voter)
    self.add_or_update_evaluation(:powervotes, 1, voter)
  end

  def score
    self.reputation_for(:score).to_i
  end
end
```

**voter.rb**

```
class Voter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :polls

  has_reputation :voter_powervotes,
                 source: [reputation: :powervotes, of: :polls]

  def powervotes
    self.reputation_for(:powervotes).to_i
  end
end
```

When I powervote() on a poll as a user and then call Voter.powervotes it returns 0. What gives? I feel like it was a miracle that I got this far on my own, but now I'm just lost. Maybe this isn't possible and I just need to manually query the database?

Comment: In the event that I'm not being specific enough, I'm want to know why, even though a row has been created for the powervote, I'm not able to know how many powervotes a user has created.

Again, maybe I just need to do a manual query where I gather all the evaluations by filtering on Target, Source, and Type in rs_evaluations.

Comment: Ok, I think I've found part of the problem and I think it all points to STI.

When I record a powervote as a user on a poll, using this setup, 3 reputations are created in my rs_reputations table.

powervotes
voter_powervotes
score

Everything seems fine, until you dig a little deeper. You see voter_powervotes' target_id seems to be pulling the wrong ID. In this case it's pulling 4 - it should be 1. I think it's doing this because Poll ID 1 has a column called voter_id and its value is 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple solution that was found with the help of the gem's creator [Katsuya Noguchi](https://github.com/kn). There's no need to create a :voter_powervotes reputation inside of the voter model when you can just count by whom the power_votes were evaluated by. I def felt like a dolt after seeing how simple it was. Hopefully this helps someone else!

voter.rb

```
def powervotes
  Poll.evaluated_by(:power_votes, self).count.to_i
end
```

GitHub issue reference: [#63 STI pulls wrong target_id for non-primary reputation](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system/issues/63)